# why my website meta description tag is not update in Google search?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

I have developed this website

thereelthing.com.sg/

how ever after 3 week which i have updated the meta tags in my website, this meta tag is does not appear the same on google search!!
( http://thereelthing.com.sg/ )

Search Reasult:
Clients | The reel Thing
http://thereelthing.com.sg/clients/The Reel Thing, Video Company, thereelthing.com.sg , mandanemedia.com.

Search link (on page 3)!
https://www.google.com/
search for : the reel thing sg

Do u know is there any way i could update the Google search result more faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your site has a page rank of 0, google won't be indexing that very often. Have you set up google webmaster tools for it and do you have a xml site map?

Comment: Thanks peter i just did webmaster, but i have not done site map :| , i have not studies well about SEO. I am going to add sitemap

Answer (score 2):

Your title tags don't explain much about each page and your meta descriptions are all identical and full of content that is not relevant (repeated domain names?).

I would not be surprised if Google decided to ignore them in most cases and make up their own text. They do that.

Comment: @ Tiggerito thanks, Could you tell me what do u mean by title tags? you means <title>HTML Reference</title> one :D ?

Comment: yes, those are the title tags, and they are what google will use as titles in the SERPs (search engine result pages).  Those and the descriptions are important, the descriptions are used as the content in the SERPS.

Answer (score 0):

When you update your meta tags, you need to re-index your web page. Try with social bookmarking and blogs to cache again by search engine robots.

Make backlinks with new meta keywords to get fast and accurate results. New meta tags will be affected whenever your web page is re-indexed.